# how to add dynamic data with jquery add function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code where I used jQuery code to duplicate a table, the original table is working fine with php fetch  query, but the duplication process doesn't work if i add php code to it, but if the php code removed it works.

```
  <form action="" method="post" name="addusers" id="addusers">
            <div class="felements"><select name="proname" type="text" required class="tfield2" id="proname">
                <option id="0">-- Select Provider --</option>
                <?php $prov = $con->query("SELECT * FROM providers"); while ($vall = mysqli_fetch_array($prov)){ ?> 

                <option id="<?php echo $vall ['ID'];?>">
                    <?php echo $vall ['provname']?>
                </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select></div>

            <div class="felements"><input name="invodate" type="text" required class="tfield" id="invodate" placeholder="Invoice Date"/>
                </div>
                    <div class="felements"><input name="Save" type="submit" class="button" value="Save" style="width: 91%;"></div>

        <table class="table table-borderd table-hover felements">
            <thead>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Claimed Amount</th>
                <th>Exchange Rate</th>
                <th>Claimed Amount (LYD)</th>
                <th>Insurance Type</th>
                <th><input type="button" value="+" id="add" class="btn btn-primary"></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="detail">
                <tr>
                    <td><select name="comname[]" type="text" class="form-control comname"><option id="0">-- Select Company --</option> 
                <?php $comp = $con->query("SELECT * FROM companys"); while ($vall = mysqli_fetch_array($comp)){?><option id="<?php echo $vall ['ID'];?>">           <?php echo $vall ['company']?></option><?php } ?></select></td>
                    <td><input name="claimed[]" type="text" class="form-control claimed" required placeholder="Invoice Amount"/></td>
                    <td><input name="rate[]" type="text" class="form-control rate" required placeholder="EX Rate"/></td>
                    <td><input name="netclaimed[]" type="text" class="form-control netclaimed" required placeholder="Invoice Amount"/></td>
                    <td><select name="reinsurer[]" type="text" class="form-control reinsurer">
                        <option id="0">-- Select Reinsurer --</option>
                        <option id="1">تكافلي</option>
                        <option id="2">تجاري</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <th><input type="button" value="-" id="remove" class="btn btn-primary"></th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th class="total">0</th>
                <th>LYD</th>
                <th></th>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        </form>





    <?php require('../includes/footer.php'); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#add').click(function(){
                addnewrow();
            });

            $('body').delegate('#remove','click',function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

            $('.detail').delegate('.claimed, .rate', 'keyup',function(){
                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var qty = tr.find('.claimed').val();
                var rate  = tr.find('.rate').val();
                var amt  = (qty * rate);
                tr.find('.netclaimed').val(amt);
                total();
        });

    });  

        function total(){
            var t = 0;
            $('.netclaimed').each(function(i,e) 
            {
                var amt = $(this).val()-0;
                t += amt;  
            }); 
            $('.total').html(t);
        }


        function addnewrow()
        {
            var tr = '<tr>'+
                     '<td><select name="comname[]" type="text" class="form-control comname"><option id="0">-- Select Company --</option>                                          <option id=""></option></select></td>'+
                     '<td><input name="claimed[]" type="text" class="form-control claimed" required placeholder="Invoice Amount"/></td>'+
                     '<td><input name="rate[]" type="text" class="form-control rate" required placeholder="EX Rate"/></td>'+
                     '<td><input name="netclaimed[]" type="text" class="form-control netclaimed" required placeholder="Invoice Amount"/></td>'+
                     '<td><select name="reinsurer[]" type="text" class="form-control reinsurer"><option id="0">-- Select Reinsurer --</option>       <option id="1">تكافلي</option><option id="2">تجاري</option></select></td>'+
                     '<th><input type="button" value="-" id="remove" class="btn btn-primary"></th>'+
                     '</tr>';
                $('.detail').append(tr);
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] without PHP (e.g. only rendered HTML and script) - if the PHP breaks the HTML, then show that too

Comment: Also I would expect to see `$('.detail').on("keyup",'.claimed, .rate',function(){` instead of `$('.detail').delegate('.claimed, .rate', 'keyup',function(){`

Comment: i posted the whole code so any one can try it, if i couldn't explain it well in my description.

Comment: But we cannot try it without saving on a server - if you have JavaScript issues we do not need to see any pho

Comment: define "doesn't work". You get an error of some sort (e.g. in the browser console, or from PHP)? Or there's some unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @mplungjan thanx again for your comment, i'm actually new to coding and i'm still learning, so i'm not professional enough to identify or summarize my prb in detailed short code, sorry for the inconvenient.

Comment: @ADyson thanx for your response, my prb is  that addnewrow function doesn't work if there is a php code within the row codex.

Comment: No need, right click in your browser and use that rendered HTML. Click TIDY to format it nicely and check the result shows the issue

Comment: @HamzaMAshur "ddnewrow function doesn't work". Yes I know, you already said that. But still, what does "doesn't work" mean? Is it an error message (in which case tell us the message), or something else that you didn't expect to happen?

Comment: P.S. in this section `<td><select name="comname[]" type="text" class="form-control comname"><option id="0">-- Select Company --</option> 
                <?php $comp = $con->query("SELECT * FROM companys"); while ($vall = mysqli_fetch_array($comp)){?><option id="<?php echo $vall ['ID'];?>">` you need to add `</select></td>` at the end - you don't close either the select or the table cell. This will produce invalid HTML.

Comment: And all your options need value, not ID: `<option value="....">`

Comment: Have alook at this: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/u30v3fcj/ That is the type of stuff we need

Comment: @mplungjan .. thank you the demo is so helpful for me to explain my prb, now please use the demo you made to add new row, you will find that the first row contain the options to select, but the replicated row dose not, if you just insert the option data as static HTML in the replication code it will work and show the option, but if you fetch them for a database will not fetch, and the add new row button will stop working as you click and nothing happen ... thank you again for supporting me.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your comment, please check my above comment,  i think you will find the prb, and please point me to what you need to know, i'm looking foreword for your help.

Comment: Then you need to ajax the content unless you clone: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/565ruzd9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to AJAX the content if the selects are different OR clone instead of inserting static rows:

```
function addnewrow() {
  $('.detail').append($("tbody.detail tr:eq(0)").clone());
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/565ruzd9/)

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it was very helpful. thank you again for your patience with me and your kind support.